# Flask Mail Exception

Tags: python, email, web, flask, flask-mail

I checkout 6b(The book "Flask Web Development", Chapter 6 Mail), and I want to send an email for test.But it raised an exception. I use virtual machine(CentOS 7). The exception as follows:

```
(venv)➜  flasky git:(09d4ff0) ✗ python hello.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
192.168.182.1 - - [10/Jan/2015 22:03:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.182.1 - - [10/Jan/2015 22:03:10] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
192.168.182.1 - - [10/Jan/2015 22:03:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 811, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 764, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "hello.py", line 63, in send_async_email
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/qinf/flasky/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 491, in send
    with self.connect() as connection:
  File "/home/qinf/flasky/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 144, in __enter__
    self.host = self.configure_host()
  File "/home/qinf/flasky/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 158, in configure_host
    host = smtplib.SMTP(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 250, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 362, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I use local ip, but i can connect with the internet. I changed some configurations: mail, port, username, password. The hello.py as fllow:

```
import os
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hard to guess string'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.163.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
#app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
#app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = mail
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = password
app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] = '[Flasky]'
app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SENDER'] = 'Flasky Admin <flasky@example.com>'
#app.config['FLASKY_ADMIN'] = os.environ.get('FLASKY_ADMIN')
app.config['FLASKY_ADMIN'] = another_mail

manager = Manager(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
moment = Moment(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
mail = Mail(app)


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role %r>' % self.name


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username


def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)


def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    msg = Message(app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + ' ' + subject,
                  sender=app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
    msg.body = render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs)
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[app, msg])
    thr.start()
    return thr


class NameForm(Form):
    name = StringField('What is your name?', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db, User=User, Role=Role)
manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404


@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.name.data).first()
        if user is None:
            user = User(username=form.name.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            session['known'] = False
            if app.config['FLASKY_ADMIN']:
                send_email(app.config['FLASKY_ADMIN'], 'New User',
                           'mail/new_user', user=user)
        else:
            session['known'] = True
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=session.get('name'),
                           known=session.get('known', False))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I can not deal with this problem.

Comment: Are you sure your host is using TLS?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The problem is really caused by the TLS, I disable the option MAIL_USE_SSL and change the port corresponding to the mail server I use. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use SSL.

```
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
```

also you can try to remove the TLS from your configuration

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much .It is solve my issue